# Where is $f(x)=|||x-2|-2|-2|$ not differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My task is to find **where**

> $$ f(x)=\left | \left | \left | x-2 \right | -2 \right |-2 \right|$$

**is not differentiable**. I know that a function is not differentiable where it has a 'kink' or 'corner' and I think that is the case here.

I have some sort of an idea for a solution, but I don't know how do it properly.

Comment: Where are the 'kicks' of the absolute value function ?

Comment: I think OP means "kink".

Comment: Can you graph $f(x)$? Start by graphing $y=|x|$, then $y=|x-2|$, then $y=||x-2|-2|$ and then $f(x)$.  That will give you a good idea of where the non-differentiable points are.

Comment: As one commentator already pointed out, a glance at [a graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/at3lridexl) should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for values of $x$ which produce $0$ inside each set of absolute value signs. These are the points where there are 'kinks'. Here's an algebraic solution:

First, the inner kink
$$\left|x-2\right|=0$$
$$x-2=\pm0$$
$$x=2$$

Then,
$$\left|\left|x-2\right|-2\right|=0$$
$$\left|x-2\right|=2$$
$$x-2=\pm2$$
$$x=0 \qquad x=4$$

Finally,
$$\left|\left|\left|x-2\right|-2\right|-2\right|=0$$
$$\left|\left|x-2\right|-2\right|=2$$
$$\left|x-2\right|-2=\pm2$$
$$\left|x-2\right|=0 \qquad \left|x-2\right|=4$$
$$x=2 \qquad\qquad x=-2 \qquad x=6$$

Taking all these together, we have
$$x=-2,0,2,4,6$$

Answer (score 2):

[image: $|||x-2|-2|-2|$]

Does this solve your problem ?

NO!

Then look at this..

[image: better]

Try to guess which color line is which..

Yet a problem?

Compare @CurtisBechtel 's answerwith the graph

Comment: I think this would be more instructive, if it included a link showing how the graph was generated. There's already one in the comments, if that helps. :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure How about this approach?